# Утилита PS / KILL

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash

Вывести N первых процессов, отсортированных в порядке убывания
совокупного времени выполнения в режиме ядра (cumulative system time). Параметр N
передается как аргумент командной строки.

Comment: Что пробовали самостоятельно?

Comment: Не знаю с чего начать даже...

Comment: `KILL` в сабже имеет некий смысл?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Насколько мне известно, статистики по ядру и пользователю, команда *ps* отдельно не выдаёт. Но, если смотреть суммарное время, то нечто вроде:

```
ps -el | grep -v -e'00:00:00' | awk '{print $13, $14}' | tail -n+2 | sort -r | head -n3
```

Поясняю по отдельным командам конвейера:

- *ps -el* Выдаёт расширенную информацию по всем процессам
- *grep -v -e'00:00:00'* Исключает из списка те процессы, время которых равно нулю
- *awk '{print $13, $14}'* Выводит только время и имя программы
- *tail -n+2* Убирает заголовок таблицы
- *sort -r* Сортирует по убыванию
- *head -n3* Печатает участников, занявших первые три места.

Ну, Вам надо только оформить это в виде shell-скрипта заменить в последней команде -n3 (фиксированное значение == 3) на $1 - первый параметр в командной строке этого скрипта.

Comment: Спасибо большое

Comment: *awk* — это не *shell*.

Comment: **awk — это не shell** - Не понял... Но ведь и *ps* это тоже НЕ шелл.. И даже ls - это тоже НЕ шелл.